# Code snippet has a different behavior on Chrome when running in modal or post

Tags: support, bug, google-chrome, stack-snippets

I am using Chrome on a Mac, and noticed that some snippets were not working as expected. The interesting part is that when you edit the snippet (on the modal) they run fine; but when you run the snippets from the post, they don't behave in the same way as they did on the modal.

Here is a snippet in which you can see the issue:

```js
function animation() {
  document.querySelector(".box").classList.toggle("flip");
}
```

```css
.box {
  transition: 1s ease;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  height: 250px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px 0px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

.box.flip {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.front, .back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.front {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translatey(-500px);
  margin-top: 500px;
}

.back {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="front">
    Front
    <button onclick="animation()">Flip card</button>
  </div>
  <div class="back">
    Back
    <button onclick="animation()">Flip card</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Steps to replicate:

1. Press the "Run code snippet" button above
2. Click on the "flip card" button on the snippet

   *The card will flip from white to black, but it will go suddenly all white*.
3. Click on the [edit] link for the post
4. Click on the "edit the above snippet" link (a modal will open with the code)
5. Press the "Run" button

   *The card will flip from white to black, and it will remain like that*.

I ran some tests, and the issue doesn't seem to happen on Safari or Firefox, just on Chrome. I have been able to replicate the issue only on Chrome for Mac for the following versions:

- 75.0.3770.142 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- 77.0.3859.0 (Official Build) canary (64-bit)

Comment: I cannot reproduce in Edge or in Chrome Canary. As it's not reproducible in the Canary version, it's highly likely that a future Chrome update will fix the problem.

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog I just tested on Chrome Canary for Mac and the issue is there. I am using: Version 75.0.3747.0 (Official Build) canary (64-bit)

Comment: I tested it today on version 75.0.3770.142 (Official Build) (64-bit). **The issue still happens**.

Comment: Could be a platform-specific issue, as I tested this on Windows and wasn't able to reproduce.